# "latex it!" button (add-on for Thunderbird) not accessible?

Tags: 12.04, installation, thunderbird, latex

They say here that it [works](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/latex-it/reviews/) great after..

> manually adding the "LaTeX it!" button

But how does on manually adds a "LaTeX it!" button?
without it there is no way to use this add-on. I'm 
not sure this is a ubuntu specific issue so if you 
know of a better outlet for asking this question, 
please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean, how to install that *add-on*? Also, what version of Thunderbird do you have?

Comment: thunderbird 17.0.5. I have installed that add-on+restarted thunderbird. I just see no way of using it (my friend told me there a 'latexit button on the windows version of thunderbird that appears but i don't get any)

Comment: But did you *activate* it? You have to choice the downloaded file to install it from mozilla thunderbird. And then you will see something like [this](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/previews/full/38/38803.png?modified=1331247702), do you see the button there, that is the button that you *should* have.

Comment: I install it from within thunderbird ('get-add-on') now it seems enabled (it offers me the option to disable or remove it. There is also a 'preference' button but nothing in there about activating). I have no button on my toolbar so i can't use this add on

Comment: Did you get something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/sXb7vtF.png) after the installation?

Comment: @Lucio: no-no I checked this and all my Autodetection results are green V's (e.g. Latex is up& running on my system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found out:

The first time, you have to compose a new message,
right click on the new message toolbar,
click on customize
and drag the latexit button (which is now visible) to the message toolbar.

It'll stay there afterwards,